# Converting values in a dictionary from string to float

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary from a pandas data frame.
My data frame has been assigned to the variable 'data'.

```
pace = {}
bos = data.values[2]
okc = data.values[3]
pace[bos[1]] = bos[2]
pace[okc[1]] = okc[2]
```

My problem is, the values in the data frame that are numbers are in the data frame as string and not float. I want to convert them to float. I would prefer to convert the values after inside of the dictionary with a loop using the items function. If you know any way to convert to a float though, I would love to hear. Ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify the question by adding what is the value of those variables, what you have and what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing the data you want to convert are `data.values[2]` and `data.values[3]`. If so, you can simply convert them as follows:

```
bos = [float(i) for i in data.values[2]]
okc = [float(i) for i in data.values[3]]
```

Hope this helps.